# xargs-like command templating for argv

Tags: xargs, utilities

Is there a common utility that is sort of like `xargs`, but operating on arguments instead of stdin?

For example, something like:

```
$ fictional-xargv 'echo $2 $1' foo bar
bar foo
$ fictional-xargv 'echo foo-$1-bar' 123
foo-123-bar
```

I've considered:

- `eval` but it concatenates arguments, separated by a space;
- `exec` but it expects a binary;
- `sh -c` but it doesn't admit argv.

Use case is just when there's very little manipulation of arguments to be done, so it would avoid creating a script for each invocation; or interactive use.

Comment: `sh -c '...'` seems like it should work - provided you remember that positional parameters are numbered from `$0`

Comment: @steeldriver So it does! Why is `$0` not.. I don't know what I expected, but `sh` or empty or something? I didn't even consider checking it. Thanks!

Comment: ... typically people add a placeholder `$0` like `_` or `sh` or `find-sh` depending on the application. Also don't forget to quote the shell expansions like `"$1"`, `"$2"` etc. as always to prevent unintended splits + globs